# If the reduction in Grav. PE in falling into a large Neutron Star approaches $mc^2$, shouldn't we conclude that a black hole is a large Neutron Star?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, potential-energy, event-horizon, neutron-stars

If we integrate the potential energy due to surface gravity from the surface to infinite radial distance (deep space), with a bit of basic calculus we should get

$\Delta E = mgr [J]$.

This depends only on knowledge of the surface gravity and the radius, as well as the assumption that g varies according to the inverse square law. Since the inverse square law should be universally applicable, it follows that the above energy equation should be valid for any spherical mass.

Applying this to Earth's gravity we find that when a 1kg mass falls from deep space to the surface of Earth it loses approximately (9.8x6371000) 62MJ. This is well known to be the correct figure, though it is not always calculated this way.

If we apply the formula (E=mgr) to some large Neutron stars, we find the larger the star, the closer this gets to $mc^2$ [J]. Which implies to me that the reason we don't see any larger Neutron stars is because if they get larger than the largest ones we can see, the energy of everything at the surface reduces to zero.

I understand that a change in GPE is not accepted as being related directly to a change in mass-energy in GTR, because mass-energy is constant when measured using local (variable) units of measurement. But if we use constant units of measurement, the situation is quite different.

So what reason is there not to conclude that a black hole is a Neutron Star too large to be seen?

Comment: The grav potential energy has no particular reason to be limited to mc^2. That's not the threshold for being a black hole. It's down to how compact the mass is.

Comment: @safesphere Yes that's because General Relativity sees things from a local measurement perspective. The fact that there is a change in energy occurring is undeniable to anyone who has tried lifting something and burning energy in doing so. My point is that what has traditionally been referred to as GPE is in fact a change in mass-energy if we choose to measure it with a (any) fixed unit of time. In sport this would be known as using a level playing field.

Comment: @BobaFit I'm suggesting that the limiting factor is $gr=c^2$. And it explains why the surface gravity of a black hole reduces with increasing radius. Of course the density affects g.

Comment: @safesphere You're as confused about momentum and energy as Einstein was. Energy is a scalar and when a mass accelerates, it gains momentum (a vector) not energy. The momentum it gains is capable of producing energy that is referred to as kinetic energy. Gravity is a process of conversion of energy to momentum. And don't assume that I haven't studied gravity in as much depth as you have. My understanding of gravity is deeper than yours will ever be and is certainly not limited to lifting of weights.

Comment: @AlanGee I have deleted my comments since they are not helpful in your case. Good luck with your question.